# Windows Platform ClearCase Server Migration from 7.1 to 8.0

Tags: clearcase

We will be starting our migration soon and got following questions.

Platform --> Windows 2003 to Windows 2008
ClearCase --> 7.1.1.2 to 8.x
Clients also Windows.

1. Got around 200 users and about 120 VOBs data size is about 900 Giga. IBM recommend 16 GB and quad core processor. But is this sufficient for 200 users?
2. We got about 20 VOBs configured for multisite with one site which is closed now. Should we require multisite license? Is there any way to make it use normal license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IBM recommend 16 GB and quad core processor. Is this sufficient for 200 users ?

Yes, I used similar specs. The real limitation isn't around the users, but the number of vobs managed, and their associated `vob_server.exe`.

Also, check the [ClearCase system Requirements for Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036569).

> We got about 20 VOBs configured for multisite with one site which is closed now.

I would recommend at least one multisite license to complete the migration, but once the [export/import is done](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266219), you could simply remove all replica registered to the vob, and see if that vob can be used with a simple ClearCase regular license.
(Although [the vob itself seems to remember the deleted replicas](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124225))

> If the VOB remains replicated at the end of these procedures, MultiSite licenses will be required for all users who will be accessing the VOB.
>   The steps assume that this is a 1 way move, and that you wish to de-replicate all VOBs after having "moved" them to the new host. The resulting VOBs will not draw MultiSite licenses once complete.
>
> Remove the original replica from the new replica family.
>
> Example:

```
multitool rmreplica replica:<source-site's-replica>@<local-vobtag>
```

> This is now a de-replicated VOB and will no longer require a MultiSite license.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, you are so awesome with the quick reply. You answered concern. Couple of other concern one I missed adding. 1. Any date for 8.1 as 8.0 is already 4 yrs old. Again, thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: @maestromani no information on 8.1. The most recent is 8.0.1.x: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_whatsnew.htm, with 8.0.1.5 listed as the most recent in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023148.